# How do I convert a SQLCHAR[200] type to std::string without remove characters?

Tags: c++

How do I convert a `SQLCHAR[200]` type to `std::string` without remove characters?

I've tried this way :

```
std::stringstream sstream;
sstream << str;
std::string str;
sstream >> str;
```

But, this wouldn't removes each characters after the ' ' (space).

For example, `AB CDEF O` becomes `AB`.

Comment: [SQLCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't SQLCHAR a typedef of unsigned char? You should just be able to do

```
SQLCHAR sqlchar[200] = ....
std::string str(200); // size 200 string
std::copy(sqlchar, sqlchar + 200, str.begin())
```

Comment: @juanchopanza, why have you deleted your answer?

Comment: @Luciekulza I got it wrong so many times, and Sway got it right first time. So I preferred to improve this answer with an example.